# Haskell in java, how can i implement "any"(haskell) in java?

Tags: java, haskell

So how can i implement "any"(Haskell) to java?

The "any" haskell code:

`any p = foldr' (\x y -> p x || y) False`

and my first try is this, but i dont know how i write `p x` in java.

```
boolean any(List<A> xs) {
return foldr(x -> y -> x==y || y, false, xs);
}
```

Comment: Please explain the Haskell code thoroughly so you demonstrate you understand it.

Answer (score 2):

You would write `p(x)`, BUT your Java implementation doesn't take `p` as an argument. I think your signature should be

```
boolean any (Predicate<? super A> p, List<A> xs)
```

Comment: `p` is missing wildcards, which would make this annoying to use. It should be `Function<? super A, ? extends Boolean> p`, or even `Predicate<? super A> p`.

Comment: Right, forgot about `Predicate`.

Comment: `? extends Boolean` is pretty silly, even if Predicate didn't exist. Boolean is a final class.

Comment: @amalloy Type != class. Indeed, `Boolean` has a subtype in Java: the null type. Of course, you can't actually name the null type to use it. However, it stands that Java's type system is consistent with `Boolean` having subtypes (e.g. Scala extends it with singleton types), and it's a bad habit to assume there are none. Also, correctly written generic code will sometimes spit out `? extends Boolean` (e.g. subbing `A = Boolean` into `? extends A`), and then your users have to eta-expand to fix the mismatch. Best just make your "library code" flexible.

Comment: @HTNW, and this is why I'm not a huge fan of Java generics. Trying to keep straight where it's appropriate to use `? extends A` versus `? super A` is just silly. This should be handled by the `Function` class. (I can't imagine a use case where, e.g. `Function<? extends A, ? super B>` is anything but wrong. `Function` arguments should _always_ be `? super A` and return types should always be `? extends B` because _that's just how functions_ work _in Java_, and not doing that by default is ridiculous.)